# python program bezier function

Tags: python, math, bezier

So I am trying to program a bezier curve using python, and unlike previously posts I have been able to find, I need to program It in such a way, that the summation adjust for how many splines there is, since I need to be able to remove or add splines.

I am basing my programming on this wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve right after the headline "Explicit definition"
so far this is what I have made

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import numpy as np
from pylab import*


fact = math.factorial
def binormal(n,i):
    koef = fact(n)/float((fact(i)*fact(n-i)))
    return koef


def bernstein(n,i,t):
    bern = binormal(n,i)*(1-t)**(n-i)*(t**i)
    return bern

f = open('polaerekoordinator.txt','r')
whole_thing = f.read().splitlines()
f.close() #these are the coordinates I'm am trying to use for now
#0.000 49.3719597
#9.0141211 49.6065178
#20.2151089 50.9161568
#32.8510895 51.3330612
#44.5151596 45.5941772
#50.7609444 35.3062477
#51.4409332 23.4890251 
#49.9188042 11.8336229
#49.5664711 0.000

alle = []

for entry in whole_thing:
    alle.append(entry.split(" "))

def bezier(t): #where t is how many points there is on the bezier curve
    n = len(alle)
    x = y = 0
    for i,entry in enumerate(alle):
        x +=float(entry[0])*bernstein(n,i,t)+x
    for i,entry in enumerate(alle):
        y +=float(entry[1])*bernstein(n,i,t)+y
    return x,y

bezier(np.arange(0,1,0.01))
```

my problem right now is that I need to do a summation of the x and y coordinates, so they become something like this

```
y = [y0, y0+y1, y0+y1+y2, y0+y1+y2+...+yn]
```

and the same for x

any pointers?

Comment: By y0, you mean the previous value of `y[0]`?

Comment: no I mean y0 as the first entry and so on to the n'th entry

Comment: I don't get the composition of your question. You start with some text about multiple splines, which I read as multiple Bézier segments. Then you continue with an implementation (which I don't like, since I'd prefer [de Casteljau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) to anything which actually computes factorials in each step), and end up with asking about cumulative sums. How are they related? Where do multiple splines come into any of this? Why do you need these cumulative sums? Do you want them applied to the input control points, or the output curve points?

Comment: if you read the wiki I also linked, you will see the benzier is a summation, and what I have been trying to do is firstly define the  binomial coefficient and secondly define the factor (n,i)*t^2*(1-t)^(n-i) and lastly put it all together in the bezier function, where my problem was I didnt know how to summate all the parts (which I now know from the answers below)
All in all I'm trying to define the bezier curve like it is written in the wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use np.cumsum http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html:

```
>>>y = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
>>>[ 0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
>>>y_cum = np.cumsum(y)
>>>[ 0.   0.1  0.3  0.6  1.   1.5  2.1  2.8  3.6  4.5]
```

Edit:

Using your example coordinates I get the following outputs:

```
x,y = bezier(np.arange(0,1,0.01))
plot(x,y)
```

[image: bezier]

```
 plot(np.cumsum(x),np.cumsum(y))
```

[image: bezier_cumsum]

Assuming this is what you are looking for!

Comment: seams to work great, but how would you plot it afterwards, then i use plot(bezier(np.arange(0,1,0.01))) and show() it shows a graph with ALOT of individual lines, and not one line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on what're you trying to accomplish, but it's probably something like this:

```
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    y2.append(sum(y[:i+1]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y2 = []
>>> for i, v in enumerate(y):
    y2.append(sum(y[:i+1]))


>>> y2
[1, 3, 6]
>>>
```

Or, the shortcut using list comprehension:

```
y2 = [sum(y[:i+1]) for i,_ in enumerate(y)]
```

Well, hope it helps!